# Access to "parent scope" in JShell

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

It seems, that `JShell` object created inside another `JShell` does not have access to parent's `JShell` scope. For instance:

```
jshell> int x = 1;
x ==> 1

jshell> x
x ==> 1

jshell> jdk.jshell.JShell js = jdk.jshell.JShell.create();
js ==> jdk.jshell.JShell@1a052a00

jshell> js.eval("x");
$4 ==> [SnippetEvent(snippet=Snippet:ErroneousKey#1-x,previousStatus=NONEXISTENT,status=REJECTED,isSignatureChange=false,causeSnippetnull)]

jshell> js.eval("int x = 2;");
$5 ==> [SnippetEvent(snippet=Snippet:VariableKey(x)#2-int x = 2;,previousStatus=NONEXISTENT,status=VALID,isSignatureChange=true,causeSnippetnullvalue=2)]

jshell> js.eval("x");
$6 ==> [SnippetEvent(snippet=Snippet:ExpressionKey(x)#3-x,previousStatus=NONEXISTENT,status=VALID,isSignatureChange=true,causeSnippetnullvalue=2)]
```

Is it somehow possible to make parent scope visible to the child one?

Comment: Do you mean to somehow access the value of `x` from `JShell` instance `js` in your sample?

Comment: @nullpointer exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929943/can-the-java-9-jshell-be-used-to-run-code-in-another-jvm) the one big caveat about JShell is: it runs in its *own* JVM.

The javadoc for [create()](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/arch/doc/jdk/jshell/JShell.html#create--) says:

> Equivalent to JShell.builder().build().

And when you follow to the javadoc for [build()](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/arch/doc/jdk/jshell/JShell.Builder.html#build--), you find:

> Build a JShell state engine. This is the entry-point to all JShell functionality. This creates a **remote process** for execution. It is thus important to close the returned instance.

In other words: most likely, you are creating *another* JVM instance where that other shell runs. So at least for now: no chances of having a *child* jshell know about its parent.

( as in: I seriously hope that this REPL feature of Java will allow at some future point to attach a JShell to an already running JVM )

Comment: Yep, that's true, it starts a new JVM. From other hand, I thought it could be some kind of special methods in JShell class which allow to bind somehow it with parent JShell. I tend to accept your answer ,but let's wait a little for other ideas

Comment: @Andremoniy Being used to [jython](http://www.jython.org/) I was really really disappointed upon finding out that jshell can **not** hook into an existing JVM. This restriction takes away half of the "usefulness" of this feature. But maybe Java 10 or so and they fix that part.